# Call a Python script from React

Tags: python, reactjs

I have a React website up and running and I need to implement a mailer - it's for a wedding website and people would fill up the confirmation form and it'll automatically send e-mail to the organizers.

I've did it before using Ajax + PHP but I've wanted to learn Python and thought this would be a great opportunity.

Ok, so I do have a Python script that correctly sends an e-mail when I run it on my machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText 

fromaddr = "from@email"
toaddr = "to@email"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Subject"

body = "Message"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain', 'utf-8'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp server', port)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "password")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Now I don't know how to proceed with the next steps:

1. Call Python script (passing parameters) from my React App;
2. Host Python script on my web server (Dreamhost).

I've already searched about Flask but I'm not sure if this is what I need.
Could someone please enlighten me?
Thanks!

Comment: My first interaction with the web and Python was through Flask. I think it is a good way into running Python on the webserver. For this question to fly though, I think you need to be more specific and at least try yourself. It does not seem to be a programming problem/question, more of a operations one.

On Dreamhost, what can you install? What Python versions etc. 

There are other more full-fledged alternatives as well as hipper ones than Flask. But give it a try and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: You'll need an endpoint that can accept HTTP requests from your react-app. Flask can be used for that, Tornado is another very simple webserver. Either way, you will most likely associate some route to some python function/class, and put your mailing code there, hence not actually "calling a script".

Comment: DreamHost currently runs Python v2.7.6 (but I can install any version).. they also give me an option to activate Passenger (which I don't know what it is). But nevermind the host, I don't even know how to call my Python script through React. Flask is indeed necessary?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'll try a few more things now.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand your question now. You want to simply call mydomin.com/somefile.py and have it execute somefile.py with python2.7 - just like you may have done with PHP?

Comment: Exactly! I just need to pass a few parameters.

Comment: In that case, yes it should be possible with [Passenger](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215769578-Passenger-overview) - alternatively and a bit clunky, if you are already running PHP you could execute your python script with [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).